# What is Windows Presentation Foundation Host?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I have a .exe of a WPF program which is crashing on a PC that is not the one where the .exe was developed, but it does have a copy of Visual Studio installed on it anyway.

When it crashes and I choose to debug it it invokes the local copy of Visual Studio which informs me that the crash happened at a particular line in "mainwindow.xaml" (N.B. not "MainWindow.xaml").  If I right-click in Windows Explorer on the MainWindow.xaml file (because I don't see the lowercase one) the only "open with" option it gives me is something called Windows Presentation Foundation Host (not, for some reason Visual Studio).

If I take that option it brings up my default Firefox browser which asks what I want to do with it, defaulting to opening it in Firefox, which gives me *another* Firefox browser which asks what I want to do with it, which gives me ***another*** Firefox browser, etc, forever.

So **what is the Windows Presentation Foundation Host** ?   And also is there any significance to the fact that the error referred to "mainwindow.xaml" and not "MainWindow.xaml", the latter being a file I actually have in my project?

This is the MainWindow.xaml file . . .

```
<Window x:Class="MyAB4D_3DLines.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:cameras="clr-namespace:Ab3d.Cameras;assembly=Ab3d.PowerToys"
        xmlns:ab3d="clr-namespace:Ab3d.Controls;assembly=Ab3d.PowerToys"  
        xmlns:visuals="clr-namespace:Ab3d.Visuals;assembly=Ab3d.PowerToys"
        xmlns:dxControls="clr-namespace:Ab3d.DirectX.Controls;assembly=Ab3d.DXEngine.Wpf"
        xmlns:dxModels="clr-namespace:Ab3d.DirectX.Models;assembly=Ab3d.DXEngine.Wpf"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid  Background="Black">
        <Border Name="ViewportBorder" Grid.Column="0" Background="Black" >

            <dxControls:DXViewportView Name="MainViewportView" PresentationType="DirectXImage">
                <Viewport3D Name="MainViewport">
                </Viewport3D>
            </dxControls:DXViewportView>

        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's a WPF Windowed app....and not an XBAP project? Seems to me its running in your Browser....https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970051(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If you want to debug a crash in an XBAP application, then do it this way. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613597(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You can alternatively do Attach to Process, on the PresentationHost. If your "app" really is an .exe windowed app...but you are hosting an XBAP inside it...then you can debug that XBAP this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24195443/debug-xbap-hosted-in-wpf-application

Comment: It is a browser add-in that can be useful to look at XAML files that were intended to be used inside a browser.  No, it is not helpful to debug your app.  Loading your solution will be helpful.  And writing an event handler for AppDomain.UnhandledException so you don't need VS every time your app falls over.

Comment: I don't know what XBAP is but I searched for the string XBAP in the source code of the program and got no matches.    The program uses a 3rd party DirectX library.  I'll add the MainWindow.xaml file to the question.